# Relative Camera Pose Estimation from essential matrix

Tags: opencv, camera, computer-vision

I want to use a single camera to estimation relative Camera Pose by frames.

For achieving this, following steps are adopted.

1. calibrated camera get the camera parameter K
2. Finding point corresponding using SIFT/SURF
3. Fundamental Matrix Identification ;using the findFundamentalMat（），and input the matches points 2D
4. Estimation of Essential Matrix by E = K'FK and modifying E for   singularity constraint
5. Decomposition Essential Matrix to get the rotation, R = UWVt / UW'Vt (U and Vt are obtained SVD of E) ,and get the translation t;

But after  doing that,the  translation t is too small.assume the initial camera position is(0,0,0).After camera moving forward 20cm,the next pose is(0,0,20),the real translation should be 20cm .The level of the two is quite different.

what's wrong? how to obtaining the real translation from translation matrix?Could you help me?

Comment: are your camera calibration parameters scaled the way you assume it? If your new pose is 20 and you assume it to be 20cm, might it just be scaled in cm? What kind of value would you expect?

Comment: @Micka   Thank you ,the  camera calibration parameters are in pixel。And actually the camer move  forward 20cm .so I think the translation should be (0,0,20);The camera is monocular.I want to get the real translation in CM.

Comment: @Micka  Thank you ,the camera calibration parameters are in pixel。And actually the camer move forward 20cm .so I think the translation should be (0,0,20);The camera is monocular.I want to get the real translation in CM.

Comment: afaik in camera calibration parameter there is encoded how big one pixel is on the sensor (= in real world). How do you perform calibration?

Comment: ah ok, your measured translation "should be" (0,0,20) but it isn't? So what does your algorithm measure instead?

Comment: @Micka       I use the Matlab to calibrate,[link](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/).From the calibration tool,I get the calibration parameter.I  manually measured translation ,and the translation is 20cm.   But from  algorithm measuring ,translation is (0.9,-0.3,0.004). I have doubt s about  solving Fundamental Matrix with 2D points in  image plane. And how to up to the scale?

Comment: sorry, got no practical experience with fundamental/essential matrices yet. Maybe you find some test images with known calibration/position etc online to test your algorithm and reduce error sources.

Comment: @Micka   Thank you all the same.  Monocular  camera drops the depth information.May be the factor of that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Essential matrix is only defined up to scale. The translation vector you get from decomposing E is a unit vector. You cannot get the actual distance between the cameras in world units without more information, such as a reference object of known size in the scene.